# What are the relative frequencies of cases in Latin?

Tags: morphology, declension, statistics

Latin has seven cases: nominative, accusative, genitive, dative, ablative, vocative, locative.
What are their relative frequencies in classical Latin?

I suppose an answer would have to be based on analyzing an annotated corpus or something similar.

I have no other motivation for this than idle curiosity, although I suppose one could use this information to argue that one really should learn all the cases — at least the first five.

Comment: see fig. 12.1 and 12.4 https://global.oup.com/booksites/content/9780199283613/figures/ (Pinkster 2015)

Comment: cf. https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/6961/39

Comment: and Pinkster 1990 http://perseus.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.19:6:2:1.NewPerseusMonographs

Comment: @AlexB. Thanks! Those make a great addition to the current answer. I'd be happy to see an answer based on those. I may write something up myself, but it'll take a while before I can find a good moment.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the [Perseus Database](https://textkit.com/greek-latin-forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=69895), the frequency of the cases is as follows:

**Nouns** (19630):

- accusative 31.6%
- ablative 25.8%
- nominative 22.6%
- genitive 13.6%
- dative 4.6%
- vocative 1.2%
- locative 0.2%
- unknown 0.4%

**Adjectives** (7497):

- accusative 33.0%
- nominative 31.6%
- ablative 21.8%
- genitive 8.6%
- dative 4.2%
- vocative 0.6%
- locative 0.0%
- unknown 0.0%

**Pronouns** (6289):

- accusative 33.1%
- nominative 32.0%
- ablative 13.1%
- dative 13.1%
- genitive 8.5%
- vocative 0.1%
- unknown 0.1%

Comment: Thanks! That was very quick for such a thorough answer. ;)

Comment: I find the unknown to be generally high. I guess unknown should account the times of ambiguity?

Comment: @d_e Certain words in certain contexts are ambiguous as far as assigning the case with any certainty. This was done "semi-automatically" and revised as much as possible. You can find more information about the PerseusDL Treebank at [Github](https://github.com/PerseusDL/treebank_data/tree/master/v2.1/Latin).

Comment: Thank you for this answer and the link to the database. Both are very helpful.